# IntelliJ 2018.1 Tomcat Run Issues - Run/Debug Config "Include dependencies with 'Provided' Scope"

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I upgraded my instance of IntelliJ from 2017.3 to 2018.1. In the ***Run/Debug Configurations*** window, I see an option that I didn't see previously: ***Include dependencies with "Provided" scope***. This is checked by default. With that field checked, I am not able to run my spring-boot application. Every time I start my application, I get bean creation exceptions such as this:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory'...

When I uncheck that field, my application runs correctly. My questions are, what does that field control and is there any issues that may result from unchecking it considering it was checked by default?

Here is the 2017.3 ***Run/Debug Configurations*** window:
[image]
Here is the 2018.1 ***Run/Debug Configurations*** window with the pertinent field indicated:
[image]

Comment: Please see the discussion at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048 for the background of adding this option.

Comment: Wow, looks like quite the discussion on this topic! Thanks for providing.